# Kotlin Junit5 ValueSource as an array variable

Tags: kotlin, junit, parameterized-unit-test

I have a map of key and values and I want to add the keys as array to ValueSource but I've got error.Where am I wrong?

Here's my code

```
   private val id = mapOf("abc" to 10001,"def" to 955,"ghi" to 804,"jkl" to 805)
    private val ids:Array<String> = id.keys.toTypedArray()
    
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = ids)
    fun idConverterImpl(memberId: String) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to annotations must be compile time constants. `ids` is not a compile time constant. It is the value of `id.keys.toTypedArray()`, which must be computed at runtime.

You can instead write it inline like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"])
fun idConverterImpl(memberId: String) { ... }
```

If you don't want to duplicate the keys of your map in multiple places, you can instead use a `MethodSource`. This allows you to non compile-time constants as the parameters of your test, by providing a method that will generate the parameters.

You will need to make your map and values static:

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    private val id = mapOf("abc" to 100016040, "def" to 955803, "ghi" to 955804, "jkl" to 955805)

    @JvmStatic
    private val ids by lazy { id.keys }
}
```

By using a property delegate on `ids`, I made Kotlin generate a `getIds` method, that I can then refer to using `MethodSource`:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("getIds")
fun idConverterImpl(memberId: String) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours keys mapping and fetching is ok, you are probably having some other kind of issue my guess is `private` your tests cant get to data